# Python Regular Expression of long complex string

Tags: python, regex

So I am scraping data from a webpage and the received data usually is as followed:

`233989 001 0 / 49 T R 4:15 PM - 5:30 PM 205 IST Building 01/13/14 - 05/02/14 Controls View (814) 865-8947 266200 002 0 / 43 M W F 10:10 AM - 11:00 AM 110 IST Building  01/13/14 - 05/02/14 Controls View (814) 865-8947`

I am trying to split the data from the pattern ###### (6 numbers, i.e. `233989`) to the phone number which represents the end of the current data line (i.e. `(814) 865-8947`) Because I know it'll always end with 4 numbers I came up with the expression:

`(^[0-9]{1,6}$[^[0-9]{1,4}$]*[0-9]{1,4}$+)+`

This does not seem to work though. Can anyone lend a helping hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
r'(\d{6}.*?\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}) ?'
```

Then rebuild it on `$1\n`

Like so: http://regex101.com/r/lG4gG5

Python:

```
import re

s = '233989 001 0 / 49 T R 4:15 PM - 5:30 PM 205 IST Building 01/13/14 - 05/02/14 Controls View (814) 865-8947 266200 002 0 / 43 M W F 10:10 AM - 11:00 AM 110 IST Building 01/13/14 - 05/02/14 Controls View (814) 865-8947'
spl = re.split(r'(\d{6}.*?\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}) ?', s)
for line in spl:
    print line
```

Comment: Made it a little simpler, didn't need that second capture group at all.